# Connect to Oracle with TOAD

Tags: oracle, toad

Is there any way to connect to Oracle using TOAD without installing an Oracle client?

Comment: You don't connect *to* TOAD. TOAD is just a database tool. You use it to connect to a database, most often remote databases. Sql Developer isn't an Oracle client library either, it's a database tool just like TOAD.

Comment: Did you try to connect to a database and got an error? What error?

Comment: its saying that, No oracle client  installed in local

Comment: The Oracle refers to the Oracle Client, a separate library, not SQL Developer. That's provided and distributed by Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

If you check [Installation Guide](https://support.quest.com/de-de/technical-documents/toad-for-oracle/14.0/installation-guide), **Database requirements** specify:

> An **Oracle client must be installed** and configured on the system where you are running Toad (...)

Therefore, I'd say *no* is the answer to your question.

Comment: oracle sql developer doesn't need it, right?

Comment: Right, it does not.

Comment: _"oracle sql developer doesn't need it, right?"_    Correct.   Plus, SQL Developer is free.